# Shape path too large to be rendered into a texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to solve this problem but so far the only thing i've found is disabling the hardware acceleration. It actually works but it makes the scroll laggy is there a way to solve this problem but keeping the hardware acceleration on?

Comment: By searching through SO I see that such warning is common, but still it would be more helpful if you add some more information when does it happen and the code that you use.

Comment: The code is too long to post it here, it used to work properly. But now the graphs are a bit longer so the path also is longer and that's when error occurs

Comment: I had the same problem and I found a solution using `Matrix`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72504556/1124866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the only solution was using software rendering and optimizing the code so it can scroll smoothly. In my case I was drawing the curve in the onDraw method and it was called everytime I scrolled redrawing the curve several times per second, this was fast using hardware acceleration but really slow on software. Now I draw the curve in a bitmap only once and set the bitmap as background of the view redrawing only the pointer onscroll making the scroll smooth even without software acceleration. I hope this can help anybody with the a similar problem!