# Draw path bigger than maximum bitmap size

Tags: android, path

I want to draw a path bigger than `canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth()` and/or `canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight()` inside a View that will be zoomable.

Especially on older devices (Android 9 and previous), this leads to:

> Path too large to be rendered into a texture

or

> Shape too large to be rendered into a texture (16388x16388, max=16384x16384)

Adding to the View `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint)` does not draw my actual path (also if smaller than maximum bitmap size), stating:

> View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 12462208 bytes, only 2073600 available

I tried to play with `canvas.setDensity()`, `canvas.setMatrix()`, `canvas.clipRect()`, but no joy.

Here is a simple Activity that can't draw the path on old devices:

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FrameLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.addView(new BigPath(this));
    }

    class BigPath extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Path path = new Path();
        public BigPath(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            path.lineTo(canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth(), canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight());
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's possible to split programmatically the path in smaller pieces, but I don't know how. Note that my actual path is generated automatically and more complex than a simple diagonal line, so I can't just split it manually in advance.
First downscale the path and then enlarge the generated bitmap?
Reducing the final bitmap resolution could be an option, but having at the end the original path size, because there are other Views the path is aligned to.

How could this path bigger than maximum bitmap size be drawn?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a `Matrix` to downscale the path, and then to upscale the canvas.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float maxPath = 100000; // Something bigger than max bitmap size
    path.lineTo(maxPath, maxPath);
    int maxBitmap = canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth() - 10; // Limit 10 px stricter
    float stroke = 3;
    if( maxPath > maxBitmap ) {
        // Downscale path
        float factor = maxBitmap / maxPath;
        matrix.setScale(factor, factor);
        path.transform(matrix);
        stroke *= factor;
        // Upscale canvas
        factor = maxPath / maxBitmap;
        matrix.setScale(factor, factor);
        canvas.concat(matrix);
    }
    paint.setStrokeWidth(stroke);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

This makes possible to draw a huge path and output it at the original size.

Keeping the provided `MaximumBitmapWidth` will lead to something like:

> Shape too large to be rendered into a texture (16388x16388, max=16384x16384)

Because a generated bitmap is some pixel bigger than the actual path size.
So it's necessary to reduced a little bit the limit.

There is no need to consider `canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight()`, as it is always equal to max bitmap width.

The only drawback of this method is that **the final bitmap resolution could be reduced**, depending on how much the first scale `factor` is less than 1 (and the second one more than 1).